# Flush rule in Texas holden poker

Tags: flush

Flush rule in Texas holden poker:
if all 5 cards of board hits as one and board become fluùsh by king, queen, 9, 7 and 3. 
then player 1 hold card 6 of the same cards on board and the player 2 holds card 4, would the pot split or player 1 win the pots?

Comment: Poker hands have 5 cards. All 5 cards play. K-Q-9-7-6 defeats K-Q-9-7-4. If that 3 on the board had been an 8, then they would split the pot, both having K-Q-9-8-7.

Answer (score 0):

king, queen, 9, 7, 6
is higher than
king, queen, 9, 7, 4

The highest hand wins the pot.